# C# ListView Relay Command Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, xaml

Can someone help me with the list view with grid. I want when you click on an element that a function is called and I get the current item. I already have the following XAML code:

```
<ListView Name="lstView" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SimResults}" >
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SelectedItemCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=lstView}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridView.Columns>
                <GridViewColumn Header="FileUniqueID" Width="Auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=FileUniqueID}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="XML" Width="Auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=XML}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Request" Width="Auto" HeaderStringFormat="" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=RequestShort}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="RequestDate" Width="Auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=RequestDate}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Response" Width="Auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=ResponseShort}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="ResponseDate" Width="Auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=ResponseDate}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="ResendCounter" Width="Auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=ResendCounter}" />
            </GridView.Columns>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

In the cs file I have the following functions:

```
private Item selectedItem;
private RelayCommand selectedItemCommand;
this.selectedItemCommand = new RelayCommand(this.SelectedItems);

        public Item SelectedItem
        {
            get { return selectedItem; }
            set { selectedItem = value; OnPropertyChanged("SelectedTrends"); }
        }

        public RelayCommand SelectedItemCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return this.selectedItemCommand;
            }

        }

        private void SelectedItems(object obj)
        {
            this.requestXml = this.selectedItem.DisplayName;
        }
```

When I select an element the **selectedItems** and I can get the item.

Hi I tested the code above and it worked fine. But I have problem. I have different tabs, when I click a different tab with the left click it always runs the SelectionChanged event and I get a Null reference exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to create a property for the "SelectedItem" from the listView.

So, in your VM:

```
private YourType _selectedResult;
public YourType SelectedResult
{
    get { return _selectedResult; }
    set { _selectedResult= value; OnPropertyChanged("SelectedResult"); }
}
```

And bind this proprety on your ListView:

```
<ListView Name="lstView" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SimResults}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedResult}">
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply now the code above works but the SelectionChanged event also runs when I change to a different tab and I get a Null reference. Do you know how I can accomplish the the event is only accepted for a click on an item on the list view.

Comment: You don't need the SelectionChanged Event anymore. When you select another element in your ListView, the setter of SelectedResult is executed. (Maybe you have to specify the "Mode=TwoWay" in your binding in SelectedItem)

Comment: Hi thanks for you reply. If I debugged the code and select an item in the listview with left click the getter and setter isn't called I updated my current code in the main post.

Comment: Maybe can you also describe me how I can get things work with my first aproach, as now the SelectionChanged event runs when I change to a different tab and I get a Null reference. The event should be only accepted when you make a click on an item on the list view, so I can do it with Command and Relay Classes.

Comment: Did you try the event "ItemSelectionChanged" ?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late response. I tried it now but it didn't worked but catching the Null exception worked.

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure you initialize selectedItemCommand before InitializeComponent() in the ctor, eg:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    this.selectedItemCommand = new RelayCommand(this.SelectedItems);

    InitializeComponent();
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply now the code above works but the SelectionChanged event also runs when I change to a different tab and I get a Null reference. Do you know how I can accomplish the the event is only accepted for a click on an item on the list view.

Comment: @user2644964: what if you modify SelectedItems to return immediately in case a null is received in the parameter?